# How to add different style with jquery in same div name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how to add diferrent style in same div name with jquery?

example like this.

```
<div id="link">
    <div class="one">This is first link</div>
    <div class="one">This is second link</div>
    <div class="one">This is third link</div>
</div>
```

and i want to add different color for all text in .one
the first class one with #FFF 
the second class one with #000 
the third class one with #333

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
var $oneDivs = $("#link div.one");
$oneDivs.eq(0).css("color","#FFF");
$oneDivs.eq(1).css("color","#000");
$oneDivs.eq(2).css("color","#333");
```

That is, first select all of the divs by class, then pick out the individual ones by their (zero-based) index and set the required colours.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8kNF6/

Answer (score 5):

```
var colors = ['#FFF', '#000', '#333']
$('#link div.one').each(function(idx, elem) {
   $(elem).css('color', colors[idx]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question specifically asks how to do it with jQuery, but you do know you could do that with an nth-child css selector and not have to use javascript at all, right?

'just throwin it out there      :)

```css
#link div:nth-child(1) { color: #FFF; }
#link div:nth-child(2) { color: #000; }
#link div:nth-child(3) { color: #333; }
```